why is this happening when installing yoswup2
Downloading transitions-0.9.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (111 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 111.8/111.8 kB 44.8 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Building wheels for collected packages: python-axolotl-curve25519
Building wheel for python-axolotl-curve25519 (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [7 lines of output]
C:\Users\antou\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:318: InformationOnly: Normalizing '0.4.1-2' to '0.4.1.post2'
self.metadata.version = self._normalize_version(self.metadata.version)
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_ext
building 'axolotl_curve25519' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-axolotl-curve25519
Running setup.py clean for python-axolotl-curve25519
Failed to build python-axolotl-curve25519
ERROR: Could not build wheels for python-axolotl-curve25519, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
yowsup2 installed correctly

It's written in the error message: you need Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater
